# DC comic featuring an entire planet terraformed by blind people so it looks like Superman's head

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, superman

I have a very faint (probably from the 1960s) memory of reading a DC comic and there was Superman flying past an entire alien planet that looked just like Superman's head.

I got zero memory of the plot or anything at all, just that one image....I was a young kid giving it "Wow!"

Update:-
I've thought (headache!) hard about this one and I 'think' it might have been a planet of alien blind people that he had saved from some deadly peril, as he went to fly off a young blind girl asked to feel his face, they then spent years altering their world in gratitude. He was very surprised when he returned to check up on them.

Comment: https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Moz-Ga_(Prime_Earth)? Not Superman but Green Lantern

Comment: No, soz.... I've just looked at that but it was deffo Soop in the mystery strip

Comment: The book "*Superman: Silver Age Sundays 1963*" mentions a newspaper strip  that has Superman visiting a 'Planet of the Blind'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this the story, "Superman Under the Green Sun!," published in_**[Superman Vol. 1 #155](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_155)**_...?

From the
DC Database page for the issue:

> Superman arrives on a distant planet when he spots a monstrous creature terrorizing it's people. After disposing of the monster he realizes that all the people of this world are blind.
>
> [...]
>
> Before leaving, a woman named Petra, still waiting for her vision to be restored feels Superman's face before the Man of Steel departs.
>
> Months later as he is flying past the planet, he is surprised that the people of that world had re-sculpted the face of Drago to resemble that of Superman instead.

> SUPERMAN: **Great Scott! The planet--it's been changed from the shape of Drago's head--to mine!** But only the exiled overseers--and Drago, who is dead--ever saw me! How could the people know what I looked like while they were blind? Pera! When she touched my face, her fingertips "memorized" my features!
>
> [image: Superman Vol. 1 #155, page 19.]
>
> <sub>*Superman Vol. 1 #155* (August, 1962)</sub>